# How to submit multiple, duplicate forms from same page in Rails - preferably with one button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In my new views page I have:

```
<% 10.times do %>
  <%= render 'group_member_form' %>     
<% end %>
```

Now this form contains the fields: `first_name`, `last_name`, `email_address` and `mobile_number`. Basically I want to be able to fill in the fields of all the forms in one click which then submits each into the database as a unique row/id.

What would be the easiest way to accomplish this?

Note: The number of times do is called from a variable. Any advice welcome, thanks!

Comment: preferably you would have some model, which has_many those models for which you have a form now, and use a fields_for method here

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You should have only one form (you should put only fields in the `group_member_form` partial). In your view you should have something like:

```
<%= form_tag "/members" do %>
  <% 10.times do %>
    <%= render 'group_member_form' %>     
  <% end %>
  <%= submit_tag "Submit" %>
<% end %>
```

and in `_group_member_form.html.erb` you should have

```
<%= text_field_tag "members[][first_name]" %>
<%= text_field_tag "members[][last_name]" %>
<%= text_field_tag "members[][email_address]" %>
<%= text_field_tag "members[][mobile_number]" %>
```

This way, when the form submits, `params[:members]` in the controller will be an array of member hashes. So, for example, to get the email adress from the fourth member after submitting the form, you call `params[:members][3][:email_adress]`.

To understand why I wrote `_group_member_form.html.erb` like this, take a glance at this:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#understanding-parameter-naming-conventions.

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17775118/merge-two-forms-rails MAybe you can help me

Answer (score 0):

You can also use accepts_nested_attributes_for in your model, and use fields_for on your form.

Submitting multiple forms, afaik, only javascript, if the forms are remote: true, and you run through each of them and then submit.

```
$("form.class_of_forms").each(function() {
  $(this).submit();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively a more up to date approach using form_with and fields_for, without removing the form into a partial, could be written like this:

```
<%= form_with (url: end_point_path), remote: true do |form| %>
    <% (1..5).each do |i| %>
        <%= fields_for 'cart_items'+[i].to_s do |fields|%>
            <%= fields.text_field :first_name  %>
            <%= fields.text_field :last_name  %>
            <%= fields.email_field :email_address  %>
            <%= fields.number_field :phone_number %>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
    <%= form.submit "Submit" %>
<% end %>
```