# creating multiple objects of the same model in a single form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to create multiple instances of the same object in one form.
I have tried

```
<%= form_tag(animals_path) do %>
 <% @animals.each do |animal| %>
  <%= fields_for "animals[]",animal do |f| %>
   `//animal fields
 <% end %>
<%= submit_tag 'save' %>`
```

but got error: "undefined method `merge!' for nil:NilClass"

I have built @animals at my controller like this

```
@animals = []
 3.times do |t|
 @animals << Animal.new
end
```

using rails 3.0.7

any help is appreciated.

Comment: can you post your controller code.

Comment: I have edited my post on that

Comment: You want to use nested attributes. For nested attributes there must be a parent model. But in your case you use form_tag . so when it tries to merge child attributes to parent model, it didn't find any parent model so the error is produced.

Comment: for more details check this http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

Comment: I can't do it in nested attributes, because i have no parent model. do you have any idea how to do it without nested attributes?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is not possible with nested form you can use your own trick to do this. There is some questions on stack overflow like this  [How to submit multiple, duplicate forms from same page in Rails - preferably with one button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9395970/how-to-submit-multiple-duplicate-forms-from-same-page-in-rails-preferably-wit)